# How to force font on RDLC - interpret html tags

Tags: rdlc, reportviewer

I chose in RDLC (VS 2017) the Markup Type option: interpret HTML tags
can I force font for those placeHolders?
I would like to get the tags but to override the font. (I need ol, ul but not styles).
Any idea how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

FontFamily can be override by setting the font property to a different size then default.
For example: setting the HTML placeholder to 10pt was ignored but setting to 12pt forced the whole HTML to be 12 pt.